# C++ operator overloading for rationalNumber

Tags: c++, object-oriented, rational-numbers

I have created a `rationalnumber` class and used operator overloading function of C++.

My questions are:

1. Have I implemented the class and `<` operator correctly?
2. Objects of class can now inserted in map and set. Is that part done correctly?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class RationalNumber {
    int num;
    int den;
    bool negative;
    int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0)
            return a;
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
public:
    RationalNumber() {
        num = den = 1;
        negative = 0;
    }
    RationalNumber(int a, int b) {
        if ((a < 0) ^ (b < 0))
            negative = 1;
        else
            negative = 0;
        num = abs(a);
        den = abs(b);
        int h = gcd(a, b);
        num /= h;
        den /= h;
    }
    RationalNumber operator+(const RationalNumber &r) {
        RationalNumber added;
        added = RationalNumber(num * r.den + r.num * den, den * r.den);
        return added;
    }
    bool operator<(const RationalNumber &r) const {
        return num * r.den < r.num * den;
    }

    void toString() {
        cout << num << "/" << den << endl;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    RationalNumber r1(3, 5);
    RationalNumber r2(1, 3);
    RationalNumber r3 = r1 + r2;
    RationalNumber r4(9, 13);
    vector<RationalNumber> v;
    map<RationalNumber, string> S;
    map<RationalNumber, string>::iterator it;
    S[r1] = "1";
    S.insert(S.begin(), pair<RationalNumber, string>(r2, "2"));
    S.insert(S.begin(), pair<RationalNumber, string>(r2, "2"));
    S.insert(S.begin(), pair<RationalNumber, string>(r3, "3"));
    S.insert(S.begin(), pair<RationalNumber, string>(r4, "4"));
    for (it = S.begin(); it != S.end(); ++it) {
        RationalNumber r = it->first;
        r.toString();
        cout << it->second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified whether it works as intended?

Comment: @Mast I ran few test cases it is working fine

Comment: Then you don't need to ask if it's working correctly.  We can only review this code if it really does work.

Comment: Since you support negative numbers, add some test cases for them. Also check and see what 1/2+1/2+1/2 prints?

Comment: @ilkkachu, it prints 3/2. It should be right.

Comment: Yeah, I misread, nothing to see there.

Comment: Negative numbers are *not* correctly handled. Adding `1/2` and `-1/4` gives `-3/-4` with your code.

Comment: `(1/2) < (-1/4)` gives `true`, which is also wrong

Answer (score 2):

Style:

- Use an initialiser list for constructors, with meaningful parameter names. example at the end.
- Please use the right type for negative - true/false makes it a lot easier to read and understand inline what type negative is.
- Naming: The toString() is easier expressed by *returning* a `std::string` - that can be used as-is or forwarded to std::cout or other logs. If you want to use a log output, (e.g. `std::cout`) it can be trivially implemented using a `template operator<<` with a generic ostream input - in this case it is not required (see below)
- The `operator+` can be expressed in a single line, without the temporary `added` variable.
- it is desirable to make `gcd` an non-member file-local static function (`static gcd(int a, int b)`) the rationale being that the logic:

  - doesn't depend on the state (or const-ness) of the `Rational` object (so non-member)
  - doesn't need to access the (private/protected) innards of `Rational`(so non-static, non-friend)
- In `main`, the for loop can be shortened (in general, if a function call chain helps avoid a temp variable, do so). example at the end.

The same logic (avoiding a temp variable) holds for defining r3 and r4 inlined when adding them to the map.

- vector v is unused.
- Include what you use: `vector`, `map`, `iostream`, `cmath` (and `iterator` if you decide to use ostream_iterator.
- maps don't require an input iterator during insertion. Use `std::make_pair(a, b)` to cut down on the verbose template boilerplate.

Logical Issues:

- Translation into `abs` and `negative` is done in the ctor and not followed up well in other places. This will fail for negative test cases. *hint*: why is negative required as a member?
- adding 1/4 and 1/2 results in 6/8 - while this isn't incorrect, this defeats the purpose. Invoke gcd there.
- Depending on how you want your object to behave, handle the case of `(den == 0)`, either by explicity asserting against its occurence, or by adding special handling for arithmetic operators. You don't want a `1/0 + 5/2 == 2/0` comparison.

Constructor style preferred:

```
RationalNumber() : num(1), den(1), negative(false) {}
RationalNumber(int numerator, int denominator) 
: num(abs(numerator))
, den(abs(denominator))
, negative((numerator < 0) == (denominator < 0)) 
{
    //use gcd here
}
```

Terser loop style suggestions:

```
for (map<RationalNumber, string>::iterator it = S.begin(); it != S.end();++it) 
{
    std::cout << "comparing:" << itr->first.toString() << itr->second << std::endl;
}
```

or the even terser lambda:

```
transform(S.begin(), S.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, '\n'), 
    [] (const pair<RationalNumber, string>& p) { return p.first.toString() + " " + p.second; });
```

*edits:* 
Moved code examples to the end - as code indents don't work in between bulleted points.

Comment: ironically, I can't seem to get my code-formatting right (despite the correct indents). I'd appreciate if someone told me where my formatting went wrong and what I should do about it the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the correctness of your code, but I have a few comments about it. Anyway, you should write a few unit tests to test your classes and functions.

Here are a few suggestions and possible improvements for your code. I'm assuming that you're compiling with C++11 or higher.

1. Including `bits/stdc++.h` seems like an overkill. It results in the inclusion of many (not sure if all) libraries from the C++ standard, even though you use just a few of them. So I would replace it with an inclusion of `isotream`, `vector`, etc. This will reduce compile time and program size.
2. "using namespace" is usually considered bad practice. You should only take the parts of `std` that you need, i.e.

   ```
   using std::vector;
   using std::map;
   // and so on...
   ```
3. You should declare `int gcd(int, int)` as a static function, since it doesn't require a class object as an argument. This will also instruct the compiler to create a single `gcd` function for all objects of type `RationalNumber`, rather than create multiple instances of the same function (one in each object of the class). Declaring a function to be static is done as follows:

   ```
   static int gcd(int a, int b) {
       // insert code here
   }
   ```
4. Use instantiation lists when possible. Instead of your default constructor you could write:
   `RationalNumber() : num(1), den(1), negative(0) { }` (the body is empty, because there is nothing left to be done.). The same point applies to your second constructor.
5. You can "merge" both of your constructors into one by using C++'s default arguments feature. The result is as follows:

   RationalNumber(int a = 1, int b = 1) : negative(0) {
       if ((a < 0) ^ (b < 0))
           // more code here
   }
   The statements `RationalNumber()` and `RationalNumber(a, b)` will still work the same.
6. A good chunk of your code can be simplified andmade shorter. For example, the addition function can be written as follows:

   RationalNumber operator+(const RationalNumber &r) {
       return RationalNumber(num * r.den + r.num * den, den * r.den);
   }
7. The `toString` function can be replaced by an overloading of the `<<` operator. Here's one way of doing this, using `friend`:

   ```
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const RationalNumber& r) {
       return os << r.num << '/' << r.den << endl;  
   }
   ```

   You can then just use `cout << r` to print an object of the class in the format above. I should mention that the use of `friend` is considered bad practice by some users of the language. It can be avoided here, but using `friend` is still the simplest implementation in this case in my opinion.
8. Instead of overloading the `+` operator the way you did, you can overload the `+=` operator for `RationalNumber` and then implement `operator+` as a nonmember function via `+=`. This is considered better practice; The implementation of `operator+` is then more symmetric.
9. The statements `RationalNumber r3 = r1 + r2;` and `RationalNumber r = it->first;` require a copy constructor for `RationalNumber`. Since you didn't define one, the compiler uses a default copy constructor, which simply copies the value of each field in `RationalNumber`. This works fine in this case, but I would also add the following decleration to the class:

   ```
   RationalNumber(const RationalNumber&) = default;
   ```

   This way it's clear that you intended to use the default copy constructor, and didn't just forget to write a specialized copy constructor;

Comment: I downvoted for 5 reasons: 1. `iostream.h`, `vector.h`. 2. `using std::cout` and `using std::endl`. 3. Very strange statement about `gcd()` function without any justification. 4. No mention to avoid `std::endl`. 5. Bad formatting of the code. For #5 please use 4 spaces after newline to make it a code block (or just select it and hit ctrl+k). Making `gcd()` static is not good idea in my opinion, but it is arguable decision.

Comment: I am curious: What is bad about gcd() being static?

Comment: @MartinR, that's why I said it is arguable :) I think it is pretty useful to stand on it's own, so may be putting it with other useful algorithms into it's own namespace, and then just invoking it.

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek: 3. Since `gcd` is a private member function, it can't be used outside the class. 4. The usage of `std::endl` is quite common in the C++ code I've come across. I know that `'\n'` is preferable in some respects but in this case it doesn't matter much which of these you use. 5. Fair point. This is my first post in CR, so I'm still not familiair with all of the formatting options here. I edited my answer to try and make it look nicer. Apologies. I didn't understand your objections (1) and (2). Can you elaborate on them?

Comment: @Mark, I apologies for being a little rude. I think you assume that functions are objects in C++. They are not (It is explicitly mentioned by the C++ standard). The difference between `std::endl` and '\n' is that the first flushes the buffer and puts newline, which may have impact on performance. for #1, `iostream` is C++ header, and everyone is used to that. `.h` files make people think that it is either C header or user created header. You have only very few cases where you want to write `usng xxx;`. Swap expression is one of them.

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek: Thanks for clarifying that.